# I'm having issues in running this bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Hello guys so I was trying to create a script that lists all files in the current directory, the parent of the working directory, and the /boot directory
here is what I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -la ls -la ../ ls -la /boot
```

I have already made the file executable. The problem comes in when I run it.
The error states;

```
ls: cannot access 'ls': No such file or directory
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You'd have the same thing running this on a regular command line; it's not a script-specific issue (and thus not a programming-specific issue either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ls -la ls` tells the `ls` command to look for a file or directory named `ls`, which doesn't exist.

If you want multiple commands on one line, they must be separated with a semicolon (`;`).

```
ls -la; ls -la ../; ls -la /boot
```

If you split the commands onto multiple lines, the semicolon becomes optional:

```
ls -la
ls -la ../
ls -la /boot
```

Or you can just pass multiple directories to `ls` like so:

```
ls -la . ../ /boot
```